# What maps have mobile AA (Consoles)

Tags: battlefield-3

Which BF3 maps can I find the AA vehicle on PS3?

Comment: There's the mounted AA, which doesn't move, and the mobile AA, which people hoard.  I don't know if mounted-AA kills count towards the mobile-AA's upgrades (or *any* upgrades, for that matter).

Comment: Are you playing on PC or Console?

Comment: They do not count, but I've had more luck actually driving around the mobile AA killing infantry (once you get infra red unlock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming you are on PS3** based on your Battle-Log the only two maps with mobile AA to my knowledge are:

- Wake Island (Conquest (and Rush I think))
- Noshaar Canals (Rush)

The small number of maps with available mobile AA is probably why you haven't seen it yet. It spawns far back in the base at each set of points in Noshaar and it spawns I believe at the airfield in the hangar on Wake Island Conquest.

Comment: -1 I don't have wake island, and I never play Rush, but I have been in a mobile-AA multiple times.

Comment: Well considering you play on PC that doesn't matter lol. This is Console. PC has them on way more maps. And if you look at the OP battle-log you can see that his platform is PS3.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was different for PC and PS3 *(that's very odd, considering it's easier to fly with a controller than a keyboard/mouse; I'd think **more** AA would be necessary on console, if anything)*.  I'll revoke my -1 :)

Comment: Yeah, I think its a DICE fail. Firestorm and Caspian should have mobile AA. Also yeah I used a joystick to fly in BF2, the mouse just doesn't do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

They are mainly on the large conquest maps that have air vehicles, and are very hard to get because people hoard them and hide in places with them. It all depends on what map you are on but they will only spawn at your main base not any of the checkpoints.

But generally if the map has flying vehicles it will also have AA's.

For example:
[image]

Comment: Cool, where did you get this map? Are there a whole set of them?

Comment: I assume there is, I just google'd vehicle placement in battlefield 3.  I'll look around to see if there is a set of them for ya.